# How to create a HttpServletRequest instance in Swing application

Tags: java, servlets

I have a desktop application made in swing, and I need to create HttpServletRequest Object to pass it to another application through Web-Service, so please suggest me something good to create request object in simple class.

Comment: Even if you can do this I don't believe it would be good practice. If you already have a web service set up could you use that API to communicate with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring has nice implementations of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse called MockHttpServletRequest/Response.  Javadoc link [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html).  Although intended for testing, they work very well for cases where you need to pass internal servlet objects around.

The classes are in the org.springframework.test jar.

Comment: BTW, I agree with Josh about dubious practices.  OTOH, you don't always have control over the APIs you need to use.